# Некорректно работают вместе setCenter и balloon.open

Tags: yandex-maps-api

При поиске по собственным объектам пытаюсь реализовать плавное перемещение на объект и автоматическое открывание балуна, но работает все через раз, т.е. иногда правильно отображается, иногда, когда балун открывается, центр смещается куда-то.

Грешил на то, что центр не успевает "доехать", но во-первых, координаты точки остаются неизменными (она ведь не двигается), можно проверить выводом на экран, во-вторых, пытался реализовать через колбек (код с ним), но никаких изменений.

Примечательно, что первый результат всегда правильный, дальше - рандом.
Если какой либо функции нет, то все работает прекрасно, центр всегда там, где нужно, с балуном так же

```
  map.setCenter(res.geometry.getCoordinates(), 4, {duration: 750, checkZoomRange: true}).then(function () {

map.balloon.open(res.geometry.getCoordinates(), res.properties.get('balloonContentBody') , {})

})
```

Comment: Вроде бы, решилось банальной сменой местами функций. Позже напишу, так ли это

Answer (score 0):

Такая же фигня.
Нормального решения пока не нашел. Сначала центрирую карту(setCenter), а потом по setTimeout открываю балун.